# Multi-line comments in Xcode

Tags: xcode

Is there a way to comment various lines at the same time in Xcode IDE? Selecting which lines to comment, then clicking somewhere et voilá.. the /* ... */ characters wrapping the code.

Thank you.

Comment: Still today, with Xcode 7, the short answer is **NO**. We all know the 'CMD + /'  shortcut (comment/uncomment). I'm still waiting for a non-plugin shortcut for selecting a block and wrapping it with /* ... */

Comment: Best method to use block comment in Xcode
http://stackoverflow.com/a/38368766/1556386

Answer (score 146, accepted):

<kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>7</kbd>

or

<kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd>

This inserts `//` in front of every selected line.

Comment: Is there a way to remove multiple lines comments instead ?

Comment: @Patrick: I haven't got Xcode anymore, so I can't test it. But I'm pretty sure pressing the same combination again uncomments the lines.

Comment: It works for me, at least for objective-c files. The menu item can be found at Editor->Structure->Comment Selection.

Comment: It can also be done by: right-mouse click -> structure -> Comment selection.

Comment: Great point @mani - this allows for multi line comment and uncomment

Comment: why this answer is awarded multiple times if question is to put multiple line shortcut like /* */ . I want to know is there any shortcut key to comment multiple line like /* */ this.

Answer (score 9):

Xcode Version 6.1

Shortcuts:

To Comment: Select the code to be comment, ⌘ + /

To uncomment: Select the code an press  ⌘ + /

Also see taskbar Editor>Structure "(un)Comment Selection" as user 2137640 pointed out.

Answer (score 7):

I've been using the <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>7</kbd> for years, but now in `Xcode 13.1` it just started to open the help menu instead of commenting the selected block.

Apparently the new command for commenting a selection of code is:

<kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>?</kbd>

#### Edit:

Another solution is to deselect "Show Help menu" in settings > keyboard > App Shortcuts

[image]

Comment: This is the answer! Thanks dude, you made me happy today.

Answer (score 5):

The answer is actually very simple if you want to comment a continuous sequence of lines. Select the consecutive lines, then simply press <kbd>⌘ /</kbd>.

I have no idea how to comment multiple non-consecutive lines. Maybe somebody else can help with this, if it is even possible (I doubt it.)

Answer (score 4):

There is such a function in the menu. Try: *Edit->Insert Text Macro->C->Comment Section*.
It will create a (multi-line) comment around the currently selected text.

However, using the menu is probably often slower than manually inserting the comments. But, you can also bind a key to the menu item via the preferences key binding settings.

Comment: Edit->Insert Text Macro->C->Comment Section

Comment: Thank you dmeister. It's slower, yes. And also leaves uncomment feature out. Thank you for you readiness.

Answer (score 4):

For single line Comment use  <kbd>⌘+/</kbd>

For multiline Comment you need to install [`CComent plugin`](https://github.com/flexih/Xcode-CComment)

to install plugin manager use [alcatraz](http://alcatraz.io/)

Comment: @EladG not the same. `cmd + /` will use multiple single-line comments (`// one line text...`), but the CComment plugin will use a single multi-line comment (`/* multi-line text... */`), just like in C.

Answer (score 3):

new Xcode 14:
Keys: Command + '

[image]

Comment: Why, Apple, why are you changing such stuff...? :)

Answer (score 2):

In Turkish keyboard cmd + *

You can use uncomment and multiline comment.

Answer (score 1):

in Xcode 7.x

Shortcuts:

To Comment: Select the code to be comment, ⌘ + /

To uncomment: Select the code an press ⌘ + /

Answer (score 1):

For XCode 14 and a german keyboard layout it's command - ß

Answer (score 0):

Got it!  You have to un-indent the lines so the comments are the first character on the line, not a tab or whitespace - then pressing CMD+/ works.  Just tried it in XCode 5.1.1, works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

This worked !

Higlight the desired lines then press **Command + /**

The same rule goes for uncommenting.

Answer (score 0):

For xcode 8 -> 
sudo /usr/libexec/xpccachectl 
restart your computer

Answer (score 0):

For me, with italian keyboard layout but english language on XCode 14.3, the multi-line (selection) comment shortcut is

> ⌘ '