# Comment multiple lines in Xcode 9

Tags: comments, xcode9

How can we comment multiple lines in Xcode 9. I know about `Command + /`

But This inserts `//` in front of every selected line.

But I want it like `/*......*/`

Comment: Often wondered the same thing myself...

Comment: This is an answer from a similar question
https://stackoverflow.com/a/38956204/7333829

Answer (score 0):

Xcode does not provide that type of comment `(/* .. */)` in shorthand in any version so nothg different in x-code 9 regarding this,

check this -> https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/49473

So for code commenting do anyone of follow

1. `cmd+/` is used for `//` the multiple lines,
2. For `/* ... */` either you have to manually
3. can create code snipplet. No other option is available.

**Code Snipplet**

[image]

Comment: it is used for `//` for single line comment or group comment

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik Select number of lines and then press `cmd + /`, then selected lines are commented. Thats what I mean.

Comment: I thought there would be a option as Xcode while creating viewcontroller creates this one 
    /*
     // MARK: - Navigation
     
     // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
     override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
     // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
     // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
     }
     */

Comment: @KrishnaMeena Unfortunately question is not related to segue :/

Comment: Yes question is not related to segue but what I mean is xcode creates sample code for segue and by default commenting it also like /*......*/