# Auto-generated documentation format for Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm able to automatically generate documentation in Xcode with <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd>+<kbd>⌥ Option</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd>.
Result then looks like:

```
/// <#Description#>
///
/// - Parameter bar: <#bar description#>
///
/// - Returns: <#return value description#>
```

I'd like to generate it to following format:

```
/**
  * <#Description#>
  *
  * - Parameter bar: <#bar description#>
  *
  * - Returns: <#return value description#>
  */
```

Is there a way how to do it?
Thanks

Comment: The doc comment that is used by xcode supports the markdown syntax and xcode reads and formats this for quick help, If you comment in the way you want to do it, xcode won't recognise it properly and won't display the quick help documentation properly. I would suggest you stick to xcode's format to get the most out of it

Comment: That is not true. This format also provide quick help properly. There was a mistake that I forgot to add dashes before "Parameter" and "Result" but with them it works in the same way.

Comment: Check this -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13212288/is-there-a-shortcut-to-make-a-block-comment-in-xcode

Comment: I'm surprised that works in the same way, even if you use the methods in the link above to create a shortcut or snippet, it won't auto populate the params and returns value if your function has them, so I don't think there is a way to do it without creating an xcode plugin, which i'm not even sure you can do anymore (not used them in a long time)